# Windows MFC: adjust child dialog to a tab control display area

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mfc

I am creating some dialog-based MFC application (C++) and need to use tab control. Here is the code where I try to adjust child dialog to a tab control display area (Visual Studio 2015):

```
/* main dialog */
BOOL CResourceBrowserDlg::OnInitDialog()
{
   ....
   /* 
    * `m_Page` is my child dialog instance:
    * CDlgFilterPage::CDialogEx *m_Page
    */
   m_Page = new CDlgFilterPage();
   m_Page->Create(IDD_FILTERPAGE, m_FilterTab.GetWindow(IDD_FILTERPAGE));

   RECT rect;

   /*
    * `m_FilterTab` is a tab control element:
    * CTabCtrl m_FilterTab
    */
   m_FilterTab.GetWindowRect(&rect);
   m_FilterTab.AdjustRect(FALSE, &rect);

   m_Page->MoveWindow(&rect);
   m_Page->ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);

   m_FilterTab.InsertItem(0, L"Page1");
   ...
}
```

Running this i got the following:

[image]

So how should I act to get child window fit nicely within tab control?

Comment: See [About Tab Controls: Display Area](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/bb760550#display_area).

Comment: already done. actually my code is based on it.

Comment: It seems that you get tab window rectangle, not tab inner area rectangle.

Comment: but how can i get the inner?

Comment: It is explained at the article linked above.

Comment: i have done just as it explained: "Given the window rectangle for a tab control" - m_FilterTab.GetWindowRect(&rect), "you can calculate the bounding rectangle of the display area by using the TCM_ADJUSTRECT message" - m_FilterTab.AdjustRect(FALSE, &rect). It's not working!

Comment: [TCM_ADJUSTRECT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760573): *"This message applies only to tab controls that are at the top. It does not apply to tab controls that are on the sides or bottom."* Presumably, you have to [offset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/reference/crect-class#movetoxy) the window rectangle to the top-left corner of the parent's client area first, prior to calling `AdjustRect`. To find the screen coordinates, call `ClientToScreen`, passing in a `POINT pt{0, 0};`.

Comment: @VTT: `AdjustRect` sends a `TCM_ADJUSTRECT` message. See *afxcmn.inl* for its implementation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you probably want to first add a page and then position the other dialog within the client area of the tab. Otherwise, your tab window will not have the tab buttons and the size of the dialog will be larger than what you expect.

Second, you need to position the new dialog inside the client area. You have to retrieve that and then translate it based on the window area.

Here is how you do all that:

```
m_Page = new CDlgFilterPage();
m_Page->Create(IDD_FILTERPAGE, m_FilterTab.GetWindow(IDD_FILTERPAGE));

m_FilterTab.InsertItem(0, L"Page1");

CRect rcClient, rcWindow;

m_FilterTab.GetClientRect(&rcClient);   
m_FilterTab.AdjustRect(FALSE, &rcClient);

m_FilterTab.GetWindowRect(&rcWindow);   
ScreenToClient(rcWindow);

rcClient.OffsetRect(rcWindow.left, rcWindow.top);

m_Page->MoveWindow(&rcClient);
m_Page->ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
```

The result is this:

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't the arguments to `rcClient.OffsetRect` be negative? Because local coordinates are smaller than the window coordinates?

Answer (score 0):

Do not try to get the Window position in OninitDialog() function. It will show 0,0 location instead of actual position of dialog.